# Proof of a matrix trace inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, trace, symmetric-matrices

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are both positive semidefinite matrices with the same size. Prove the following inequality:
\begin{align}
\text{Tr}((A^{1/2} B A^{1/2})^{1/2}) \geq \text{Tr}(A^{1/2}B^{1/2}),
\end{align}
where the square root of a PSD matrix is defined to be the principal square root, which is also a PSD matrix.

Clearly, equality holds when $A$ and $B$ commute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the inequality that $\operatorname{tr}\left((XX^\ast)^{1/2}\right)\ge|\operatorname{tr}(X)|$. Let $X=PU$ be the [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) of $X$, where $P$ is positive semidefinite and $U$ is unitary. The inequality then reduces to $\operatorname{tr}(P)\ge|\operatorname{tr}(PU)|$, which is obviously true because all diagonal entries of a unitary matrix have moduli $\le1$.

Comment: Is it correct that your inequality is an equality if and only if $X$ is symmetric positive semidefinite and thus the inequality in the question is an equality if and only if $A^{\frac{1}{2}} B^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is symmetric positive semidefinite, which (I am not so sure about this part) happens if and only if $A$ and $B$ commute?

Comment: @Ramanujan Yes, yes and yes. The “if” in the last “if and only if” is true because $A^{1/2}$ and $B^{1/2}$ are expressible as polynomials in $A$ and $B$ respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $X$ is psd, then $(\mathrm {Tr}\, X)^2 \geq \mathrm{Tr}\, X^2$. This can be proven by elementary inequalities if you consider the above as functions of the eigenvalues of $X$.

Your inequality follows from appropriate choice of $X$.

Comment: I do not quite get this. Are you referring to something like (AB-BA)(BA-AB)?

Comment: I also don't think that this can be used to prove the inequality. Taking the square root of both sides yields $| \text{tr}(X) | \ge \sqrt{\text{tr}(X^2)}$, while the other answer uses the (in some sense reverse) inequality $| \text{tr}(X) | \le \text{tr}(| X |)$.